# Binding to ElementName depends on binding order

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, visualstates, xbind

I created simple `StateTrigger` to bind to `FrameworkElement` `Width` property. There are three dependency properties: `MinValue`, `MaxValue` and `Element`. They types are `double`, `double` and `FrameworkElement` accordingly.

And I noticed that depending on binding order it may or may not work.

This works fine.

```
<local:ElementWidthTrigger MaxValue="1000"
                           MinValue="800"
                           Element="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
```

And this is not.

```
<local:ElementWidthTrigger Element="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                           MaxValue="1000"
                           MinValue="800" />
```

Noticed that only difference in this two samples is `Element` property binding order.

In `ElementWidthTrigger` there is property changed callback for each dependency property. And when `Element` at the very top it's callback never called no matter what.

`x:Bind` solves this issue no matter what order is in use but a question remains. Can anyone explain why `Element` property is failing to bind depending on binding order?

Running on Windows 10 1803 build 17134.320.

Working example project can be found [here](https://github.com/khamitimur/BindingTestApp).

Comment: Very nice job writing this up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you reporting this issue and providing a solid repro project - this is a platform bug. I have logged it in our database and assigned to the right team. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this is an enigma! While I haven't been able to find out the reason for the problem, it really does seem like a bug in UWP. I have noticed that the simple act of adding a `x:Name` to one of the `VisualStates` will make even the `ElementName`-first order work as expected:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Test">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <local:ElementWidthTrigger Element="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                   MaxValue="1000"
                                   MinValue="800" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>

    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Blue" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

It would be great is someone from the UWP team saw this and helped out, as it probably requires insight into the internals to understand what is going on.

Comment: Good find! Didn't test a case with `x:Name`. Looks like a good temporary fix for templated controls.